# clang++ ignores -MD flag when I build with CMake and ninja

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++, ninja

I've created a very simple C++/CMake project:

CMakeLists.txt (note the `-MD` flag):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
add_executable(moop main.cc)
target_compile_options(moop PRIVATE -MD)
```

main.cc:

```
#include "moop.hh"
int main( int, char** ) { return 0; }
```

moop.hh:

```
#pragma once
```

From the project root, I run the following:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..
cat compile_commands.json
```

`cat compile_commands.json` outputs (note the `-MD` flag):

```
{
  "directory": "/home/zbardoo/moop/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/clang++      -MD -o CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.o -c /home/zbardoo/moop/main.cc",
  "file": "/home/zbardoo/moop/main.cc"
}
```

If I then run `ninja`, the executable `moop` is successfully built. However, `moop.cc.d` is nowhere to be found. But if I then copy and paste the `command` value from `compile_commands.json` and run it:

```
/usr/bin/clang++      -MD -o CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.o -c /home/zbardoo/moop/main.cc
```

The file `/home/zbardoo/moop/build/CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.d` appears:

```
zbardoo@localhost:~/moop/build$ cat CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.d 
CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.o: /home/zbardoo/moop/main.cc \
  /home/zbardoo/moop/moop.hh
```

Why doesn't `ninja` obey the `-MD` flag in the `compile_commands.json` file?

Answer (score 3):

Clang is not the culprit, it's ninga

The explanation for the missing `CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.d` can be found
if you look in the generated `build/rules.ninja` and find:

```
rule CXX_COMPILER__moop
  depfile = $DEP_FILE
  deps = gcc
  command = /usr/bin/clang++  $DEFINES $INCLUDES $FLAGS -MD -MT $out -MF $DEP_FILE -o $out -c $in
  description = Building CXX object $out
```

Note:

```
  deps = gcc
```

Then see [the Ninja manual: C/C++ header dependencies -> `deps`](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_deps):

> deps
> (Available since Ninja 1.3.)
>
> It turns out that for large projects (and particularly on Windows, where the file system is slow) loading these dependency files on startup is slow.
>
> Ninja 1.3 can instead process dependencies just after they’re generated and save a compacted form of the same information in a Ninja-internal database.
>
> Ninja supports this processing in two forms.
>
> deps = gcc specifies that the tool outputs gcc-style dependencies in the form of Makefiles.
> Adding this to the above example will cause Ninja to process the depfile immediately after the compilation finishes,
> **then delete the .d file (which is only used as a temporary)**.

(My emphasis).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the equivalent header dependency information is available through `ninja -t deps`:

```
zbardoo@localhost:~/moop/build$ ninja -t deps
CMakeFiles/moop.dir/main.cc.o: #deps 2, deps mtime 1547243911 (VALID)
    ../main.cc
    ../moop.hh
```

However, it appears that this dependency information is available whether or not I specify `-MD` through `target_compile_options`.